# Modify `/etc/hosts` file and serve per-domain pages in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, subdomain, hosts

React novice here. We have a situation in which we are going to be creating a sub-domain for every client that signs up for an app and then there will be a landing page for every client at `<client_name>.ourwebsite.com`.

The front-end for the website is going to be in React using React-Router v2.8, so when the user visits `<client_name>.ourwebsite.com`, the app needs to pick up the `<client_name>` and query the server for the data needed for landing page.

I am trying to set this up in the development environment by modifying the `/etc/hosts` file for every sub-domain name.

How do I get the React app to detect the `<client_name>` and get the data accordingly?

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by `get the data `? From where are you getting the data ?

Comment: @Panther, get the data from backend API. `<client_name>` will be passed to the API and it will return the JSON data required to render the landing page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is a plain js question. You can get the hostname using `window.location.host`. This will return you `xxx.ourwebsite.com` as result in your case. Use this to get your `subdoamin` name and send it to api.

Comment: Sometimes things are way simpler than we think them to be. Thanks!